# sub.menu's not working

Tags: menus, urls

working on a wordpress install that is in a subdirectory of another wordpress install (( thecloud99.info has wp in the root )) there is a folder in the root called clients w/ another wordpress install in chamber :: http://thecloud99.info/clients/chamber/

the problem i'm running into is that the sub.menu under members shows up correctly but doesn't actually take me to the page, instead it returns me to the home page.

??

Comment: @flashmallach: Since you get a redirect, I suggest you hook into the `redirect_canonical` filter and `var_dump()` the two arguments. If this returns anything, you can try figuring out why it does so.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem *seems* to be within your .htaccess rewrites.  First thing to try: change the permalink structure back to normal (index.php?p=375) and see if the submenus work then.  If they *do* then problem is with permalinks.

Sorry, I know this should probably be a comment not an answer, but I don't have enough points to comment.